# Convert a multi-column table to a dict of dicts

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have custom class to simulate a row in table (in database concept), each column is a string.

```
class Row:
  def __init__(self, filename, message, version):
    self.filename = filename
    self.message = message
    self.version = version
```

And I use a list to store them.

Assume I don't know the range of each column, and I want to transfer this 'table' to a dict of dicts, 
such that it would be easier to query for all rows that `filename = OOO` and `version = XXXX`. 
What would be a better way to do it? Right now I could iterate through all rows and build the range for particular column but it's kind of spaghetti code.

Comment: You need to have `class` be lowercase.  Also, it would follow convention to have `row` be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is probably something like this.  If you know your rows are immutable, you could provide a **hash** method though - that might look a little nicer.

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

class Row:
    def __init__(self, filename, message, version):
        self.filename = filename
        self.message = message
        self.version = version

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.filename, self.message, self.version)

    __repr__ = __str__

def main():
    list_ = [
        Row('abc', 'message1', 'version1'),
        Row('def', 'message2', 'version2'),
        Row('ghi', 'message3', 'version3'),
        Row('jkl', 'message4', 'version4'),
        Row('mno', 'message5', 'version5'),
        ]

    dict_ = {}
    for row in list_:
        tuple_ = (row.filename, row.version)
        dict_[tuple_] = row

    sought = ('def', 'version2')
    print(dict_[sought])

main()
```